# Refreshing Power BI SSAS dataset

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, powerbi

I'm using Power BI web preview and have SSAS as a data source. When my underlying SSAS tabular data model changes, I don't see my reports or the dataset in Power BI get updated.

Since manually "refreshing" the Power BI data set is not supported as of now, how do I make sure that my Power BI reports are in sync with the latest data?

Comment: Are you using the analysis services connector?  If so you run a trace on your Analysis Server instance you'll see if updates are coming through....  If you're not using the SSAS Connector then you'll want to look into that here https://support.powerbi.com/knowledgebase/articles/471577-configure-a-power-bi-analysis-services-connector .  If you want to understand how it work and installs see our video on youtube http://bit.ly/PBI4E

Answer (score 1):

There's a great blog on the Analysis Service connector here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2015/03/11/power-bi-analysis-services-connector-deep-dive.aspx

It includes the top trouble shooting tips. If you're still having problems, please use the "?" at the top of the power bi preview UI to ask for support.
HTH,
Lukasz

Answer (score 0):

As of now you can use Power BI Gateway, and you will have the option to update cubes on scheduled intervals, or you can live connect as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using import or direct query method? If you are using import mode you can set up an schedule refresh for that. If you are using direct query all your data is going to be updated